# Закрытие активного окна в браузере

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, можно ли предоставить пользователю возможность закрыть окно браузера (окно с моим сайтом) при нажатии на кнопку типа `<button>` с помощью JS (аналог стандартного значка окна браузера)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У встроенного объекта `window` есть метод [`close`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close). Он как раз и закрывает окно браузера. В тоже время, нужно понимать, что этот метод будет работать **только** для окон, открытых с использованием JavaScript.

Например, вот такой код работать всегда (если, конечно, браузер не блокирует открытие новых окон):

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var wnd = window.open('http://google.com');
    setTimeout(function() {
        wnd.close();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Такой код тоже будет работать, но **только** если текущее окно было открыто из JavaScript:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    window.close();
});
```

Тот факт, что не все окна могут быть закрыты с использованием JavaScript продиктован соображениями безопасности. Если в каком-то из браузеров есть некоторые трюки для обхода этого ограничения, то такие трюки я бы рассматривал как ошибки браузера и не стал бы на них полагаться.

Comment: Скажите, а для `jQuery` тоже уместно использовать `window.close();` ?

Comment: jQuery -- это JavaScript библиотека. Все что можно использовать в JS можно использовать и в jQuery.